# Search and merge objects by its parameters

Tags: python, search

I'm trying to create a method to merge multiple parametrized configuration file sections into one.

Each section can have specific section parameters and contains a payload of configuration variables. There is an examples of a few sections:

```
[MySection]
    foo = defaultbar

[MySection|color=red|shape=circle]
    foo = bar
    variable = value

[MySection|shape=circle]
    otherfoo = otherbar
    foo = anotherbar
```

Those sections are represented by following class:

```
class Section():
    # All values here are parsed from config file
    name = "MySection"

    # This is a section specific parameters
    params = {'color': 'red',
              'share': 'circle',
              'weight': 'ton'}

    # This is section variables payload
    vars = {'foo': 'bar',
            'variable': 'value'}

    def merge(self, section):
        """Merges current section vars with vars of given one"""
        # ...code here...
```

(All parameters and vars are assigned in the runtime, not statically assigned)
Section parameters may vary, some may be absent.

What I need is an algorithm to select and merge configuration sections(its variable payloads) into one by a specific section parameter values.

For example, I have a list of sections:

```
sections[0].params = {'color': 'blue'}

sections[1].params = {'shape': 'circle'}

sections[2].params = {'color': 'red'}

sections[3].params = {'shape': 'circle'}

sections[4].params = {'color': 'blue',
                      'shape': 'circle'}

sections[5].params = {'weight': 'ton'}

sections[6].params = {'color': 'blue'}

sections[7].params = {'color': 'blue',
                      'shape': 'circle',
                      'weight': 'ton'}
```

The selection and merging criteria(determined in runtime) is an OrderedDict, for example:

```
criteria = {'color': 'blue',
            'shape': 'circle',
            'weight': 'ton'}
```

Now I need to search the list of sections to find ones that fulfill this criteria at least partially. Sections which have more parameter matches must be merged later.

With given criteria sections will be merged in following order:

```
sections[0] + sections[6] + sections[1] + sections[3] + sections[5] +
sections[4] + sections[7]
```

Order of merge is important, with a possible exception for same parameters sections (e.g. 0 and 6, 1 and 3)
The generic algorithm is:

1. Search for section that have only the first parameter of criteria and merge them
2. Repeat step 1 for other parameters in criteria
3. Search for section that matches two parameters of criteria...
   and so on...

Is there an quick and elegant way to do this ?

Comment: `{'x' = 'y'}` is not valid Python syntax. To specify a dict's key-value pairs, you want `{'x' : 'y'}`.

Comment: Also, dictionaries **don't have an order**, so you can't say the "order of merge is important" - it doesn't matter what order you merged them in, the resulting 'vars' would be the same.

Comment: Yes, my bad with the syntax. By "order of merge is important" I meant that order in which section.merge() called is important(because section vars gets overwritten in some cases). Now I see that 'criteria' must be an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 0):

This will merge them in order, with the last one being the most important:

```
parameters = {}
parameters.update(sections[0])
parameters.update(sections[6])
parameters.update(sections[1])
parameters.update(sections[3])
parameters.update(sections[5])
parameters.update(sections[4])
parameters.update(sections[7])
```

It's unclear to me what you mean with "Merging criteria". Possibly you mean that some values are more important then others, but then there is no good way of doing it except looking at each parameter itself.

Update:

No, there is no quick and elegant way to do what you want.

You need to first sort your sections on how well they match your merging criteria, which needs to be a list of keys and values (OrderedDict works, but a list of dictionaries or tuples work too). Since you care about how unique the parameters are when matched, you need to have the number of parameters for the section as a part of the sorting key.

You need then take the sections in that order, and merge them. There is no workaround, really. :)

There may however be quick and elegant ways to solve your use-case, but we don't know you don't tell us why you are doing it. It may be worth asking a question about that too.

Comment: Use-case is some kind of configuration section overload. Some custom parameters(e.g. system language or software version) are determined in the runtime and must be kept in mind while parsing config file. By default program will use a parameterless section, but if config file contains a section specific to these custom parameters, default values must be overridden by its contents.

Comment: @RedPampage: That doesn't explain these importance/sorting parameters. Configuration section overload is trivial, you just use ConfigParser, and parse a global file, and then update that this a local file, and lastly override it with command line parameters.

Comment: ConfigParser will not do in my case. All sections are in one file, parser just chooses which ones to merge and which ones to throw away based on certain parameters. The idea is a lot like in windows INF files where multiple [Strings] sections can have a locale suffix to override the default values. The order of merging is determined by the number of criteria matches and position of parameter in criteria. sections[6] goes after sections[0] because it has two hits while sections[0] has one. sections[1] goes after sections[0] because its 'shape' param is after 'color' param in search criteria.

Comment: Yeah, you still haven't explained the reason for those criteria, so you still haven't really explained your use case. I still think starting a question for that might be helpful.